Error property "eclipselink.default-target-namespace" is not supported when eclipselink is on the classpath
I am getting the error "eclipselink.default-target-namespace" is not supported when eclipselink is on the classpath. I found an article https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8960
There they mention ---"Only by setting the default JAXB provider to be the glassfish implementation by setting the system property jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory CXF will work in this setting."
I want to know how to set it and where(I am using it in a Spring Boot app).

What versions of everything are you using? Could it be related to https://www.mail-archive.com/users@cxf.apache.org/msg45367.html

I was also facing a similar problem but with Quarkus App instead of Spring Boot App.
The solution was add the "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5" dependency before the "org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:4.0.3" dependency.
